# import bootstrap-datepicker missing styles Rails 4.2

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm pretty new to Bootstrap and i'm trying to get my datepicker to work. I use the [bootstrap-datepicker-rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails) gem with bootstrap-sass. But it seems that there are some styles missing when i do the [imports mentioned on the site](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails#configuration).

An import this way works:

```
 @import "bootstrap"
```

But then all the bootstrap styles are used all over the site and thats not exactly what I'm trying to achive. But with the `@import "bootstrap-datepicker3"` the datepicker is not placed at the right spot and is missing some styles.

Is it necessary to import all the bootstrap styles or should it be possible to just use the styles for the datepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was a missing bootstrap component. On the [bootstrap-sass page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#configuration) is written how to customize your bootstrap configuration. So after excluding one after another of the default components the `@import "bootstrap/dropdowns"` was the one which made the trick. Seems this one is missing in the `@import "bootstrap-datepicker"` and does also not come with `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"`.

For people facing the same problem this is how you can solve it:

1) copy your default `_bootstrap.scss` to `_bootstrap-custom.scss`

```
cp .bundle/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss app/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-custom.scss
```

OR create a new one named `_bootstrap-custom.scss`

```
vim app/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-custom.scss
```

2) If you copied the file remove all others than the following lines.
If you created a new file add the following lines:

```
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

// Components
@import "bootstrap/dropdowns";
```

I also added `@import "bootstrap/tables";` because I think it looks nice but its not necessary for slolving the problem.

3) add the reference in your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` by adding the line

```
@import "bootstrap-custom";
```

also make sure you have the line

```
@import "bootstrap-datepicker";
```

For me these steps solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` and `gem 'sass-rails'`, you should change the name of the file `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`.Then add this code in this file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```